# Error on reading json file by multiple instances at the same time

Tags: python, json

I am working on an attendance system on Local server which contains the database file in json format and when a request is made to the system via RFID the script looks into the local json file for the RFID and respond accordingly. Now the problem is that for single request it is performing well but as our script(made in Python 3.3) works on multiple threading so when two or more request hits at the same time i get an exception of "expecting object:line 1 column" ... like this. So what is the problem in the script or what can be the possible solution for this. Remember there is no online request made during the script working.

Comment: Post your code and full error description/stacktrace

Comment: Have a look at the code above. This script deals with the request made by RFID device. When this script is accessed by another script (working on multi-threading), for multiple request at same i get that error, else the script works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

close the reading instances with instance.close() after loading the values with json_object.loads().

Comment: Thanks mate ... that has solved my issue ... i only need to close that json file after taking the values from it.